# Interpreting ideal diode plot with resistor

Tags: diodes

[image]

[image]

I don't understand how the gradient is 1/R_d or how the resistor is limiting the current.

Comment: Why don't you understand this? Do you understand ohms law?

Comment: Do you understand the picture if Vt = 0? Or the diode removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recognize that the external circuit must impress a voltage, V, across this branch in order for current to flow in it.  If you let V be the variable on your x-axis you will see it i think.
[image]